# Keep the selected value after submit

Tags: jquery, html

I have a time drop down selection and i want to keep the selected value after the submit button has been pressed. Html here

```
<select name="pickupdatehour">
    <option label="00" selected="selected" value="00">00</option>
    <option label="01" value="1">01</option>
    <option label="02" value="2">02</option>
...
    <option label="23" value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

I'm not using regular php for this because i'm making a site in wordpress and i would need a ton of snippets to do this,i have this select box on multiple pages and i would need a Java or jQuery script to help me keep the selected value on each page.

Comment: You can either use a cookie or localstorage to store the value in the browser, and Javascript to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the [**jQuery Cookie Plugin**](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie), you can use it to store the value of the select into cookie every time a selection is made and whenever the form loads it would check if the cookie is set and use the value in the cookie.

```
$(function() {
    var timeCookie = $.cookie( "timeCookie" ),
        selElem = $('select[name=pickupdatehour]');
    selElem.on('change', function() {
        $.cookie( "timeCookie", this.value );
    });
    if( timeCookie != undefined ) {
        selElem.val( timeCookie );
    } else {
        $.cookie( "timeCookie", selElem.val() );
    }
});
```

[**HERE IS**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/F5ukY/) a working demo.

Comment: should i add the jQuery cookie plugin in the header of my wordpress ? I'm new to wordpress and i dont know hot to proceed

Comment: Yes, anywhere after jQuery and before you use it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above unless you're storing the value in a database and pulling that out each time your best bet would be either a cookie or localstorage. Personally I've found localstorage to be easier to work with and unless you need IE7 support you should be fine to use that.

http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

You could try something like this (untested):

```
// On submit
var pickupdatehour = $('#pickupdatehour').val()
localStorage.setItem('storedPickup', pickupdatehour);

// On the pages that have the select box
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var loadedPickup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedPickup'));
  $('#pickupdatehour').val(loadedPickup);
});
```

Edit: Sorry missed that it was name not ID in your select box. Use the `select[name=pickupdatehour]` instead of the #pickupdatehour as a selector.