# keep value for dropdown ( asp.net ) after page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, reload

I am building up my dropdown (asp.net dropdown) from a response object I get off a Combobox ( asp.net telerik combobox )

```
 var theName = response.value.Names;
 var theVal = response.value.Values;

 var theCode = '<select name = "my_dropdown"><option>Select Id : </option>';

 for (i = 1; i < (theName.length - 1); i++) {
     theCode += '<option value="' + theVal[i] + '">' + theName[i] + '</option>';
 }

 theCode += '</select>';

 $('[id$=ddlDropDownDefault]').html(theCode);
```

On a page refresh , The dropdown loses it's scope and goes back to being blank until another item in the combobox (which is generating the response object) is selected .

I want it to retain the last list of object if a page reload happens. I am looking for a jquery solution.

The above piece of Jquery is being run when the 1st combobox changes selected item. I hope I've explained myself in a proper way. I've looked into this solution [Keep the selected value after submit - Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879248/keep-the-selected-value-after-submit) but I'm not sure where to call it as my dropdown is being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches, but probably just easiest to save to web storage:

Here is a plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-to-Save-Form-Data-In-Web-Storage-DataSaver.html

Depending on the complexity of your form, it may be just as easy to do it your self.