# Keepvalues=True in web2py when not using SQLFORM

Tags: python, web2py

When using a form defined with SQLFORM in the controller, one can conveniently set the `keepvalues` argument to `True` so that when the form is submitted the values are stored and the form prepopulated.

Is there an easy to achieve this result when the form is built in html and the controller only defines the variables used in the fields?

I can't use SQLFORM as it doesn't allow for the insertion of cascading drop-down menus.

**Edit 1:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879248/keep-the-selected-value-after-submit) provides a way of solving the problem but I still wonder if there is an easier way.

In form.html I added `{{response.files.append('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js')}}` before `{{extend 'layout.html'}}` and then this script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    var timeCookie = $.cookie( "timeCookie" ),
        selElem = $('select[name=FIELD_NAME]');
    selElem.on('change', function() {
        $.cookie( "timeCookie", this.value );
    });
    if( timeCookie != undefined ) {
        selElem.val( timeCookie ).change();
    } else {
        $.cookie( "timeCookie", selElem.val() );
    }
});
</script>
```

With FIELD_NAME designating the field containing the value of interest.

**Edit 2:** Here is a simplified example of what I have.
*In the controller:*

```
def form():
    types = db().select(db.Types.ALL)
    modes = db().select(db.Modes.ALL)
    return dict(types = types, modes = modes)

def filter():
    modes = db(db.Modes.name == request.vars.type_name).select(db.Modes.ALL)
    result = [OPTION(mode.name, _value = mode.id).xml() for mode in modes]
    return (result)

def on_submit():
   a function that does the insertion in the 2 dbs
```

*In the view (simplified):*

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{=URL('default', 'on_submit')}}" method="post">
div class="form-group row">
        <label for="type_name" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-form-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name='type_name' 
                id="type_name" 
                onchange="ajax('filter', ['type_name'], ':eval');">
            {{for type in types:}}
            <option value="{{=type.id}}"
                {{=" selected='selected'" if str(type.id) == request.vars.type_name else ""}}>
                {{=type.name}}
            </option>
            {{pass}}
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="mode_name" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-form-label">Mode</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select name='mode_name' id="mode_name">
                {{=modes}}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I can do something like

```
def form():
     form = SQLFORM.factory(field('type',requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.Types.id, '%(name)s')),
    Field('mode'))
    return dict(form =form)
```

and

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form.custom.begin}}
Type: <div>{{=form.custom.widget.type}}</div>
Mode: <div>{{=form.custom.widget.mode}}</div>
{{=form.custom.submit}}
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#no_table_type').change(function() {
          ajax('filter', ['no_table_type'], ':eval');  
        });
    });
</script>
```

But how do I get the field 'mode' to display the output of the ajax call (modes) like it does in html?

**Edit 3:**
This seems to work.

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form.custom.begin}}
Type: <div>{{=form.custom.widget.type}}</div>
Mode: <div>{{=form.custom.widget.mode}}</div>
{{=form.custom.submit}}
{{=form.custom.end}}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#no_table_type').change(function() {
          $('#no_table_mode').empty();
          ajax('filter', ['type'], 'no_table_mode');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a form with custom HTML, you can still make use of the `form` object generated by web2py to help fill in parts of the HTML, as described in the [Custom Forms](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-forms) documentation.

In particular, you can use the input widgets generated by web2py via `form.custom.widget[fieldname]`. If you don't want the entire widget for a given field, you can instead get just the input and display values via `form.custom.inpval[fieldname]` and `form.custom.dspval[fieldname]`.

You can probably also use the standard `SQLFORM` generated form layout along with cascading drop-downs via a combination of custom widgets (which you can specify in the model definition) and Javascript.